# Matplotlib: Creating plots with parallel loops & seaborn

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a handful of kernel plots using a parallel loop. The loop works when I use a bar chart, but goes awry when I use a kernel plot. I'm new to python so I assume I'm missing something pretty obvious - any suggestions? Thanks!

oh and `len(schools) = 3`

```
#the kernel plot
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
gs1 = GridSpec(1,len(schools))
sp1 = [plt.subplot(gs1[0,i]) for i in range(len(schools))]
colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
schools2 = [[data1....],[data2....],[data3......]]
for ax, i in zip(sp1, range(len(schools))):
    ax = sns.kdeplot(schools2[i], bw=.5, color = colors[i], lw=1.8, vertical=True, alpha=.5)
```

.

```
#the bar plot
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
gs1 = GridSpec(1,len(schools))
sp1 = [plt.subplot(gs1[0,i]) for i in range(len(schools))]
colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
test = [1,2,3]
for ax, i in zip(sp1, range(3)):
    ax.bar(1, test[i], color = colors[i])
```

Comment: Try calling `sns.kdeplot` with `sns.kdeplot(..., ax=ax)` to control where the plot ends up.

Comment: @mwaskom thanks so much! did you want to post that as answer so I can select it appropriately?

Comment: By the way, a simpler way to set up the plot would be `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using matplotlib plotting functions directly, there's a difference between doing, e.g. `plt.bar(...)` and `ax.bar(...)`. In the former case, the plot will be drawn on the "currently active" axes, while the latter case the plot will always go onto the Axes bound to the `ax` variable.

Analogously, with seaborn plotting functions if you just write, e.g. `sns.kdeplot(...)`, it will plot onto the "currently active" axes. To control where the plot will end up using the matplotlib object-oriented interface, most[1] seaborn functions take an `ax` parameter, to which you pass the Axes object: `sns.kdeplot(..., ax=ax)`.

1. I say most as there is a distinction between functions like `kdeplot`, `violinplot`, and many others that plot onto a specific Axes, and more complex functions like `lmplot`, `factorplot`, etc. that are whole-figure functions and can't be assigned to a specific Axes or Figure. Any of the former functions will take an `ax` argument.